# How to interpolate a string that was sent as an argument?

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments, string-interpolation

I have limited access to the filesystem, and I want to set up universal notification handler call like that:

```
notificator.sh "apples" "oranges" "There were $(1) and $(2) in the basket"
```

*notificator.sh contents:*

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $3
```

And get output looking like:

```
"There were apples and oranges in the basket"
```

Is it possible and how? I'd prefer if it was a builtin sh solution.
I'm actually trying to send the result string ($3) as a message to the telegram bot via curl post param, but tried to simplify the situation.

Comment: `$(...)`, or `${...}`? And do you really need it to be `$1`, as opposed to `$fruit1` or such?

Comment: Relevant: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/TemplateFiles

Comment: Also, it's worth evaluating whether and how much you trust your data -- some of the easy answers incur security risks (see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) before following any advice that involves `eval`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some changes to your `$3`, we can make this work easily.

First, let's define `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`:

```
$ set -- "apples" "oranges" 'There were ${one} and ${two} in the basket'
```

Now, let's force substitutions into `$3`:

```
$ one=$1 two=$2 envsubst <<<"$3"
There were apples and oranges in the basket
```

Notes:

1. `$(1)` attempts to run a command named `1` and will likely generate an error even before your script runs.  Use `${var}` instead.
2. To get this method to work, we needed to rename the variables in `$3`.
3. `envsubst` is part of the GNU `gettext-base` package and should be available by default of Linux distributions.

Hat tip to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy).

#### In script form

Consider this script:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "$3" | one=$1 two=$2 envsubst
```

We can execute the above:

```
$ sh script.sh "apples" "oranges" 'There were ${one} and ${two} in the basket'
There were apples and oranges in the basket
```

As an alternative (hat tip  again to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)), we can use a here-doc:

```
$ cat script2.sh
#!/bin/sh
one=$1 two=$2 envsubst <<EOF
$3
EOF
```

Running this version:

```
$ sh script2.sh "apples" "oranges" 'There were ${one} and ${two} in the basket'
There were apples and oranges in the basket
```

### Alternative

The following script does not require `envsubst`:

```
$ cat script3.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "$3" | awk '{gsub(/\$\{1\}/, a); gsub(/\$\{2\}/, b)} 1' a=$1 b=$2
```

Running this script with our arguments, we find:

```
$ sh script3.sh "apples" "oranges" 'There were ${1} and ${2} in the basket'
There were apples and oranges in the basket
$ sh script3.sh "apples" "oranges" 'There were ${1} and ${2} in the basket'
There were apples and oranges in the basket
```

Comment: `$1` and `$2` aren't in the environment, so how can `envsubst` see them? I'd expect that you'd need to copy them into named, exported variables.

Comment: ...ie. `fruit1=$1 fruit2=$2 envsubst <<<"$3"`, with a third argument of `There were ${fruit1} and ${fruit2} in the basket`, or such.

Comment: Copying the code from this answer as presently given ([Revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49329835/2)), *including* the `set --` line, output is `There were  and  in the basket`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Curious.  It works for me just as shown in the answer.  I copied and pasted from the answer just now and it still works.

Comment: **Oh**. See how you've got double quotes in the `set` line? So if you run it twice, the second time it's feeding back in on itself.

Comment: Make it `set -- "apples" "oranges" 'There were ${1} and ${2} in the basket'` to correct that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ugh.  That's must be it.

Comment: I'd suggest changing from `<<<"$3"` to `<<EOF`, then a line containing `$3`, then `EOF`, since the OP asked for /bin/sh compatibility.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are right again: she specified sh.

Comment: John1024, @CharlesDuffy, thank you both for providing the solution! Sadly, my OS is Synology DSM 6, which doesn't come with envsubst command for its shell, and there's some issues with enabling the package manager there, so I was hoping that some other solution exists with using just the shell builtins. However, it will still probably work on my friend's server, too bad I won't be able to test it out and run it on my own for now.

Comment: @MelodyNelson, ...an answer that doesn't require `envsubst` is doable, but if that needs to both (1) work with `/bin/sh`, and (2) be secure against malicious strings (ie. if a format string contains `$(rm -rf ~)`, in many cases you'd want to be sure that didn't get run as code), then that's trickier. If your awk has an `ENVIRON` map, that might allow `envsubst` to be implemented in awk in a way that doesn't compromise security. Does `awk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["PATH"]; exit; }'` print your `PATH` variable, or throw an error?

Comment: @MelodyNelson I have just added to the end of the answer a method that does not require `envsubst`.  Let me know if it works for you.